# Creating Azure Function to perform ETL

Tags: python, azure-functions, etl, azure-blob-storage

I am fairly new to [Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/) so I am having some trouble understanding what step to take.

I have written a code in Python which grabs a specific JSON file from a MongoDB database, flattens it and exports it to an Azure Data Lake Storage as a CSV file.

I have done some research and figured I could create an Azure Function and use a Blob Storage Trigger which can check to see whether a JSON file has been uploaded into the `test directory` and automatically execute my Python script to flatten it and export it back as a CSV file.

However, how do I now amend my Python script in a way for it to import that JSON file that has been uploaded to `test directory` rather than connecting to the MongoDB database?

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import pandas as pd
import os, uuid, sys
import collections
from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeServiceClient
from azure.core._match_conditions import MatchConditions
from azure.storage.filedatalake._models import ContentSettings
from pandas import json_normalize
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

mongo_client = MongoClient("xxxxxxx")
db = mongo_client.r_db
table = db.areas

document = table.find()
mongo_docs = list(document)
mongo_docs = json_normalize(mongo_docs)
mongo_docs.to_csv("areas.csv", sep = ",", index=False) 

#print(mongo_docs)
try:  
    global service_client
        
    service_client = DataLakeServiceClient(account_url="{}://{}.dfs.core.windows.net".format(
        "https", "xxxx"), credential='xxxxx')
    

    file_system_client = service_client.get_file_system_client(file_system="root")

    directory_client = file_system_client.get_directory_client("testdirectory")

    file_client = directory_client.create_file("areas.csv")
    local_file = open(r"C:\Users\areas.csv",'rb')

    file_contents = local_file.read()

    file_client.upload_data(file_contents, overwrite=True)

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Is it better to create an Event Grid Trigger or Blob Storage Trigger for this sort of problem?

Any help or advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, how do I now amend my Python script in a way for it to import
> that JSON file that has been uploaded to test directory rather than
> connecting to the MongoDB database?

If you use the blob trigger, you first need to transfer the data to the storage account, and then you can process the data inside the function:

```
import logging

import azure.functions as func


def main(myblob: func.InputStream):
    #just put the python script here.
    logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob \n"
                 f"Name: {myblob.name}\n"
                 f"Blob Size: {myblob.length} bytes")
```

Please be careful not to use blob output binding, you need to manually write the processing logic, otherwise, the data lake-based object will be destroyed so that it can no longer be received using data lake packets.

> Is it better to create an Event Grid Trigger or Blob Storage Trigger
> for this sort of problem?
>
> Any help or advice will be appreciated.

If your requirement is single (that is, it only needs to be executed when data is passed in from the data lake), then you can use blob trigger. The advantage of the event grid is that endpoints can be triggered by many different events.